# How to build an assembly and save it ..?

Tags: c#

There are many c# code snippets demonstrating building .net assembly.

The code run successfully but the problem is that saved assembly doesn't contain generated code. - even though I have set RunAndSave property for the AssemblyBuilder.

Could anyone tell me how to correctly build and save assembly with generated class,methods, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: What have you tried? You need an AssemblyBuilder, ModuleBuilder, TypeBuilder, etc - and the AssemblyBuilder must be configured to allow save

Comment: MSDN has a full example on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder.aspx - I don't really want to post a link-only answer, but nothing else is needed that that, and copying the text would be a bad idea...

Comment: @Mark -- copying relevant text is never a bad idea-- you can always prune it back if people complain about "too much" (which doesn't happen often). But links often die of link-rot. MS loooooves changing their systems, and links from 4 or 5 years back are often dead. Plus, adding in the "I used this and it worked just fine" is relevant context to a link.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code that I've used in demo's. It's a bit much for a quick example but it works. The saving is done in the BuildGenericType method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionEmit
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate int DoMath(int value);

        static DoMath mathFunc;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateCode(27, true);
            CreateCode(27, false);

            BuildGenericType();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void CreateCode(int value, bool square)
        {
            mathFunc = (DoMath)BuildMethod(square).CreateDelegate(typeof(DoMath));
            int result = mathFunc(value);

            Console.WriteLine("Result for {0} was {1}", value, result );

        }

        private static DynamicMethod BuildMethod(bool square)
        {
            Type[] methodArgs = { typeof(int) };
            DynamicMethod mthMeth = new DynamicMethod(
                "Square",
                typeof(int),
                methodArgs,
                typeof(ReflectionEmit.Program).Module);

            ILGenerator il = mthMeth.GetILGenerator();

            if (square)
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //Loads argument at index 0 into the evaluation stack
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8); //Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to int64
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup); //Copies the top most value on the evaluation stack, then pushes it to the top
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Mul); //Multiplies two values then pushes result to top of evaluation stack
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //Returns from the current method, pushing a return value (if present) from the callee's evaluation stack onto the caller's evaluation stack. 
            }
            else
            {
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //Loads argument at index 0 into the evaluation stack
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I8); //Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to int64
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup); //Copies the top most value on the evaluation stack, then pushes it to the top
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Add); //Adds two values then pushes result to top of evaluation stack
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //Returns from the current method, pushing a return value (if present) from the callee's evaluation stack onto the caller's evaluation stack.
            }

            return mthMeth;
        }

        private static void BuildGenericType()
        {
            //Define assembly
            AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName("domath");
            AssemblyBuilder asm = dom.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

            //Define a dynamic module
            ModuleBuilder mod = asm.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");

            //Define a class
            TypeBuilder asmType = mod.DefineType("OurClass", TypeAttributes.Public);

            //Define the generic type parameters
            string[] typeNames = { "TFirst", "TSecond" };
            GenericTypeParameterBuilder[] genTypes = asmType.DefineGenericParameters(typeNames);

            GenericTypeParameterBuilder TFirst = genTypes[0];
            GenericTypeParameterBuilder TSecond = genTypes[1];

            //Define generic constraints
            TFirst.SetGenericParameterAttributes(GenericParameterAttributes.DefaultConstructorConstraint | GenericParameterAttributes.ReferenceTypeConstraint);
            TSecond.SetBaseTypeConstraint(typeof(SomeBaseClass));

            Type[] interfaceTypes = {typeof(InterfaceA), typeof(InterfaceB) };
            TSecond.SetInterfaceConstraints(interfaceTypes);

            //Define a field
            FieldBuilder fld1 = asmType.DefineField("Field1", TFirst, FieldAttributes.Private);

            //Define method
            Type listOf = typeof(List<>);
            Type listOfTFirst = listOf.MakeGenericType(TFirst);
            Type[] paramTypes = { TFirst.MakeArrayType() };

            MethodBuilder asmMethod = asmType.DefineMethod("SomeMethod", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, listOfTFirst, paramTypes);

            //Define Method Body
            ILGenerator il = asmMethod.GetILGenerator();

            Type ienumOf = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
            Type tFromListOf = listOf.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type ienumOfT = ienumOf.MakeGenericType(tFromListOf);
            Type[] ctorArgs = { ienumOfT };

            ConstructorInfo ctorPrep = listOf.GetConstructor(ctorArgs);
            ConstructorInfo ctor = TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(listOfTFirst, ctorPrep);

            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); //Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor); //Creates a new object or a new instance of a value type, pushing an object reference (type O) onto the evaluation stack.
            il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); //Returns from the current method, pushing a return value (if present) from the callee's evaluation stack onto the caller's evaluation stack.

            //Create type and save file
            Type finished = asmType.CreateType();
            asm.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");



        }
    }

    public interface InterfaceA { }
    public interface InterfaceB { }

    public class SomeBaseClass
    {

    }
}
```

As an alternative, maybe you can try Rosyln? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With the [Microsoft documentation Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder) as reference source code, I am guessing that the important part the OP was missing was to use *the same name* for the second argument (`fileName`) when calling `DefineDynamicModule`, and for the first argument when calling `Save`, on the `AssemblyBuilder`. When using the same name in these places, the dynamically created module, and all its types etc, will be saved with the assembly.

In the example code, in the documentaion, this name is built up with `aName.Name + ".dll"` as per:

```
AssemblyName aName = new AssemblyName("DynamicAssemblyExample");
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(aName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave); // Include Save access!

ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name, aName.Name + ".dll"); // *Same name here ..*

// ... (Other code building types, methods etc.)

ab.Save(aName.Name + ".dll"); // *... and here*
```

---

Additional notes:

A comment in the example code in the documentation mentions

> "For a single-module assembly, the module name is usually the assembly
> name plus an extension."

And the Remarks section states that

> "If a dynamic assembly contains more than one dynamic module, the
> assembly's manifest file name should match the module's name that is
> specified as the first argument to the DefineDynamicModule method."

This, perhaps, is the clue to figure out to use the same name, as described above. Actually it also works using the one parameter overload of `DefineDynamicModule` and there naming the module by the file name.

**Note** that the `DefineDynamicModule(String, String)` overload is not available in .NET Core or .NET 5.0.