# Create a *.DLL file in run-time and save to a specified location in C#

Tags: c#, dll

In my program I need to create a dll file in run-time and need to save it in a specific file location. when i create this dll file in run-time i need to pass a parameter and that parameter will be stored inside dll file and automatically it will copy into specific location. How can i do it with c#. need some guide. thanks.

Comment: There are many guides [online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304655). If you have more specific question you could ask it later.

Comment: You need to show your code. The question as it is now is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agree this question is too general.  One possible approach is to use the [`TypeBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  See e.g. [Dynamically create a class in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp) and [How to build an assembly and save it ..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401717/how-to-build-an-assembly-and-save-it).